# LibGDX - How to create a rain and cloud? (Using "Particle")

Tags: java, android, libgdx, particles

I was going to rain as follows:
Various actors in a "Stage" falling vertically, being drawn randomly on the screen. (But it has a higher cost in processing and memory)

I made a simple example with particle (to whom I sent screen and full class code in the 1st post), and I realized that maybe used for particle effects:
rain
Cloud passing horizontally
mist
Sandstorm
thunder

Particles would be more interesting with, so I decided to just ask about the rain and it aparti have mold to see how would the other effects.

Forum LibGDX:
[How to create a rain and cloud? (Using "Particle")](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=12172&p=54526#p54526)

Comment: hey did you find any solution to this??